# Extracting part of lines with specific pattern and sum the digits using bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching

I am just learning bash scripting and commands and i need some help with this assignment.

I have txt file that contains the following text and i need to:

1. Extract guest name ( 1.1.1 ..)
2. Sum guest result and output the guest name with result.

I used sed with simple regex to extract out the name and the digits but i have no idea about how to summarize the numbers becuase the guest have multiple lines record as you can see in the txt file. **Note: i can't use awk for processing**

Here is my code:

```
cat file.txt | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}).*([0-9]{1})/\1 \2/'
```

And result is:

```
1.1.1 4
2.2.2 2
1.1.1 1
3.3.3 1
2.2.2 1
```

Here is the .txt file:

```
Guest 1.1.1 have "4
Guest 2.2.2 have "2
Guest 1.1.1 have "1
Guest 3.3.3 have "1
Guest 2.2.2 have "1
```

and the output should be:

```
1.1.1 = 5
2.2.2 = 3
3.3.3 = 1
```

*Thank you in advance*

Comment: How did you go from 1.1.1 to AAA?

Comment: Hi @Jack, my bad it should be the guest name, ie, 1.1.1 and not AAA

Comment: Shell programming 101 - google UUOC and then consider what `cat file.txt | sed ...` is doing. Why can't you use awk? Why tag the question with awk if you can't use awk? What other standard UNIX tools can't you use? You can't do this job with sed alone if that's what you're thinking (unless MAYBE you can come up with some horrendously complicated mess of inefficient, non-portable runes).

Comment: @EdMorton I am not allowed to (class assignment), i can pretty much use everything else, i just cant get my head around how to summarize the numbers :/

Comment: If you can't use awk which is the standard UNIX general purpose text processing tool then I assume you can't use any of the nonstandard general purpose text processing tools like perl, python, ruby, etc. either so then you're into doing it with a shell loop and see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why not to do that. So idk what to tell you.... Maybe it's a trick question :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I don't really know to do, all i know is that i don't have to care about the "performance" aspects and i can only use awk for output formatting.There is only one way to do i think and it's as you said by shell loop processing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your teacher wont let you use awk but, since beyond this one exercise you're trying to learn how to write shell scripts, FYI here's how you'd really do this job in a shell script:

```
$ awk -F'[ "]' -v OFS=' = ' '{sum[$2]+=$NF} END{for (id in sum) print id, sum[id]}' file
3.3.3 = 1
2.2.2 = 3
1.1.1 = 5
```

and here's a bash builtins equivalent which may or may not be what you've covered in class and so may or may not be what your teacher is expecting:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash
declare -A sum

while read -r _ id _ cnt; do
    (( sum[$id] += "${cnt#\"}" ))
done < "$1"

for id in "${!sum[@]}"; do
    printf '%s = %d\n' "$id" "${sum[$id]}"
done

$ ./tst.sh file
1.1.1 = 5
2.2.2 = 3
3.3.3 = 1
```

See https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/ for how I'm using the associative array. It'll be orders of magnitude slower than the awk script and I'm not 100% sure it's bullet-proof (since shell isn't designed to process text there are a LOT of caveats and pitfalls) but it'll work for the input you provided.

Answer (score 0):

OK -- since this is a class assignment, I will tell you how I did it, and let you write the code.

First, I sorted the file.  Then, I read the file one line at a time.  If the name changed, I printed out the previous name and count, and set the count to be the value on that line.  If the name did not change, I added the value to the count.

Comment: Sorted the file? i guess you have used the sort command but I don't really understand how is that possible because everything in the file begins with G - Guest

Comment: @Yznit sort works across the whole line by default, not just the first character of the first word on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Second solution used an associative array to hold the counts, using the guest name as the index.  Then you just add the new value to the count in the array element indexed on the guest name.

At the end, loop through the array, print out the indexes and values.

It's a lot shorter.